# How to get the value from command line to php(2 values)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'm running it in ubuntu, sorry i'm new here.

I'm trying to add 2 mixed numbers(whole number with fractions)

php fractions.php "1 1/7" "2 2/7"

how to get that 2 values and make it a variable from command line?
then i'll echo the output to the command line also
thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php This would do the trick ;)

Comment: or use this http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of things here to help and make things neat

edit your php.ini file, find register_argc_argv and make sure it is set to on:

```
register_argc_argv = On
```

create your fraction.php script e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
echo "arg1: ".$argv[1]."\n";
echo "arg2: ".$argv[2]."\n";
```

NOTE: the #! line, this is a clever bit so you don't need to use php on you command line when you run the script. /usr/bin/php may be different on your machine check by:

```
# whereis php
```

chmod the script so you can run from directly from the command line:

```
# chmod 755 fraction.php
```

finally run the script:
./fraction.php "1 1/7" "2 2/7"